# Rails 3: Getting the ID of a Namespaced Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, namespaces

I have a model called `Contributor`, which also acts as a namespace for several other models, such as `Contributor::Alias` and `Contributor::Reassignment`. I want to use a URL that includes the Contributor ID like so:

```
/contributors/1/reassignments/new
```

But I get this error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/contributors/1/reassignments/new"
```

My `routes.rb` file includes:

```
namespace :contributor do
  resources :reassignments
end
resources :contributors
```

I've also tried:

```
resources :contributors do
  resources :reassignments
end
```

This results in a different error:

```
uninitialized constant ReassignmentsController
```

Any idea how to approach this? Perhaps I shouldn't use a namespace that also acts as a model? I haven't seen this done in any tutorials, though it seems like it could be possible.

UPDATE:

How do you handle a deeply nested namespace model, such as:

```
resources :contributors do
  resources :reassignments, :module => "contributor" do
    resources :approvals, :module => "reassignment"
  end
end
```

Using this approach, I get the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"contributor/reassignment/approvals"}
```

My controller directory does have the following structure:

```
contributor ->
  reassignment ->
    approvals_controller.rb
```

This seems related to the first error, but perhaps it's something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear if you have a Contributor resource or not. If you do, the following in your routes.rb:

```
resources :contributors do
  resources :reassignments, :module => "contributor"
end
```

If not, try:

```
resources :reassignments, :module => "contributor", :path => "/contributors/:contributor_id/reassignments"
```

Just note that in the 2nd case you will need to construct an url and explicitly pass :contributor_id to it in calls to link_to, form_for, and similar places.

If you want to use [@contributor,@reassignment] format there you better stick to the 1st approach where yu do have a Contributor resource.

UPDATE: for three-level nesting if your controllers directories don't also nest in parallel with resources you could specify controllers explicitly, e.g.:

```
resources :contributors do
  resources :reassignments, :controller => "contributor/reassignments" do
    resources :approvals, :controller => "reassignment/approvals"
  end
end
```

But, please, don't do that. 3-and-more-level nesting is actively discouraged in Rails. See what is recommended instead here: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources

Comment: Excellent! I was unfamiliar with module routing, but it does the trick here. I've got a related question if you have the time. I have another namespace/model nested within the second layer, and I'm having a similar routing issue. I've updated my question, and if you get chance, will you look it over?

Comment: how is your controller defined inside the approvals_controller.rb? Is it Contributor::Reassignment::ApprovalsController or smth else? that may be the reason.

Comment: It's `Contributor::Reassignment::ApprovalsController`. Still no luck following your update, but I'll keep experimenting and let you know if I find the solution. If you have any other suggestions, those would be greatly appreciated, too.

Comment: how do you generate the route when you get this 'No route matches ...' error?

Comment: With `<%= link_to "Approve", @reassignment.build_approval %>`. I think you're on the right track. I haven't been sending in an ID parameter for the parent models, and perhaps that's what's causing the error.

Comment: yes, you are right, you need both objects there. so, it's probably `@approval = @reassignment.build_approval; <%= link_to "Approve", [@contributor,@reassignment,@approval], ... %>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25259/discussion-between-timothythehuman-and-moonfly)